# Add custom form to content type (Basic Page or any) using custom extesnion

Tags: 8, nodes, forms, blocks

I am new to Drupal. Actually, I have to add a custom form to the content type and it will be visible to the frontend user where they can submit their response. So I have created the form and save the response in the DB. Currently, that form is not linked with the content type. It is working on a separate URL. but I am not able to achieve how can I add that form to the specific content type?

[image]
[image]

I am using drupal 8.

Please help me with this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what something like the Webform module can do for you. Create a form with these fields and then you can use webform nodes and the block system to place the webform as a block within the node page, and the form can capture the node it was submitted from.